# Using HttpClient to get data from a json file in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am building an angular application.

I am trying to fetch some image files' locations in the asset directory through a json file. In the json file the locations of the images are mentioned. But after running the application I am getting error 404 and and says it can't locate my json file.

The browser displays this error message.

```
Object { headers: {…}, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/landingPageData.json", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/landingPageData.json: 404 Not Found"
```

My specifications :

Angular CLI: 15.0.5
Node: 18.10.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
Node : v18.10.0
OS: linux x64

I have a json file 'landingPageData.json' in the /src directory of my angular application. The data looks like this in the file.

```
{
    "photos":[
        {
            "img": "assets/images/landing1.jpg",
            "description": "Learn 100 english words effectively in 1 day!"
        },
        {
            "img": "assets/images/landing2.jpg",
            "description": "What you will learn"
        },
        {
            "img": "assets/images/landing3.jpg",
            "description": "Join today!"
        }

    ]
}
```

---

In my *app.component.ts* file, I am trying to fetch only the image files' location from the json data and store those into an Array *landingScreens*.

```
import { Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
@Injectable()
export class AppComponent {
  public landingScreens: any;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient){
    this.http.get('./landingPageData.json').subscribe((response) => {
      this.landingScreens = response;
    })
  }
}
```

---

And then in the template *app.component.html* file I am displaying those images given I have the locations of those images.

```
// 
//

<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="About"></mat-tab>
        <mat-card *ngFor="let img of landingScreens; let i=index">
            <img mat-card-image src="{{img.img}}">
        </mat-card>
    <mat-tab label="Courses"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Contact"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

//
//
```

I am trying not to import the json data cause in the future I will use an api to fetch the response which will be in json format. Am I messing up the subscribe part ? or giving the right directory location?

The landingPageData.json file is in */src* folder and the *app.component.ts* file is in */src/app *folder. And the images are in *assets/images* folder.

I have gone through all the relevant answers from stackoverflow but majority of them are very old angular versions or the answers told them to import the json file.

Comment: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-local-json-files/ I used this link when I wanted to have dummy db

Comment: You need to copy this file - as an asset - in your angular.json file

Comment: place the file in assets folder and make sure to use method type as GET

Comment: Use absolute path rather than relative. Remove `./` from http get request.

Comment: Thank you @JanatbekOrozaly !!! Your suggested solution worked  for me. But I must add I was not putting the <mat-card> tag inside the <mat-tab>. That's why even after applying your suggestions I did not get the results.

Answer (score 1):

I did not put the `<mat-card>` tag within the `<mat-tab>` first. So after I did that I put the l*andingPageData.json* file inside the assets folder.

This [link](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-local-json-files/) helped which was suggested by @JanatbekOrozaly

---

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent{
  landingScreens: any = [];
  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){
    this.httpClient.get("assets/landingPageData.json").subscribe(data => {
      this.landingScreens = data;
    })
  }
}
```

---

app.component.html

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="About">
      <mat-card *ngFor="let img of landingScreens; let i=index">
        <img mat-card-image src="{{img.img}}">
    </mat-card>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Courses"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Contact"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```